# Spell check doesn't work in protected forms in Word 2011 for Mac

Tags: spell-check, forms, office-for-mac

We have a form template many staff members use. We created it in Word 2004 for Mac, and I was told a shortcoming was there was no way to turn on the spell checker (a real hassle!).  I hoped this would be fixed in 2011, but when I open the form and save it as a .docx, the spell check still doesn't work.  Many menu choices, including Language and Spelling and Grammar are grayed.  Is there any way to get spell check in a protected, fillable form?